# What do you call a "factor" of a union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

If we have numbers $a,b$, they are called *summands* of $a+b$ or *factors* of $a\cdot b$. Given two modules $M,N$, they are *direct summands* of $M\oplus N$.

Likewise, given two sets $A,B$, they can be called *factors* of $A\times B$.  What word describes the relationship between sets $A,B$ and $A\cup B$ or $A\sqcup B$?

Comment: I have never seen this anywhere besides my own writing but perhaps “uniands” could work.